# Node js version mismatch between `node -v` and `brew upgrade node`

Tags: node.js

When I do

```
%node -v
```

I get `v0.8.2`.  I'm trying to use a feature that requires v0.10.  When I try

```
%brew update
%brew upgrade node
```

I get `Error: node-0.10.26 already installed`

Why the mismatch?

Comment: Did you install node separately from brew? If so, was it to a path within your home directory (or some place that comes before the global installation in your $PATH)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue I did:

```
%where node
```

which reported `/usr/local/bin/node`

I removed that link

```
%rm /usr/local/bin/node
```

then I relinked using

```
%brew link --overwrite node
```